# how to remove OneDrive picture album from photos.windows phone

Tags: onedrive

Recently I had uploaded some photos on OneDrive which are most personal but the album of OneDrive appearing in photos please help me to remove these photos.

Comment: Do you want to remove the pictures you uploaded from OneDrive? If so, use the OneDrive app on your phone or go to https://onedrive.live.com. Or do you want to stop photos on OneDrive from showing up in the Photos app on your phone? If so, please clarify which version of Windows is your phone running.

Comment: I want to delete those pictures which are showing in photos live album just like facebook,twitter,OneDrive.

Answer (score 3):

The photos hub shows online albums from apps that are installed that provide an online album (For example, if you install Facebook or Twitter) you'll get additional folders that can't be removed without uninstalling the associated app.

As the OneDrive app is part of the core operating system that the phone uses, it cannot be uninstalled, and will always show in the Photos app as an online folder.

Comment: This is only true for WP8. The Windows 10 Photos app lets you choose whether or not to show OneDrive albums. Hence my question about which version of the OS his phone is running.

Comment: But I still want to remove this live album from photos app.. Or tell me please how to uninstall if remove album not possible.

Comment: It is not possible to remove the OneDrive album with Windows Phone 7.x or 8.x. Once the update to 10 is available for your phone, it is apparently going to be possible then.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove those photos by going to OneDrive app on your Windows phone. 
Or you can also go to OneDrive.live.com and then sign in with same Microsoft account and then delete the photos.

Answer (score -1):

I found a workaround:

1. Delete files from OneDrive
2. Refresh Photos album, now it's gone from phone
3. In OneDrive restore your pics from recycle bin

Done!